# python code to check if a date is valid and increment the date

Tags: python

The code should check if the entered date is valid or not. If the date is valid then print "the date is valid" and if is not, then print "the date is invalid". If the date is invalid then it shouldn't increment the date. so the below code prints if the code is invalid, but doesn't print if the code is valid. The whole code works perfectly, but I want to add a part where is says "the date is valid" if it actually is.

```
date=input("Enter the date: ")
dd,mm,yy=date.split('/')
dd=int(dd)
mm=int(mm)
yy=int(yy)

if(mm==1 or mm==3 or mm==5 or mm==7 or mm==8 or mm==10 or mm==12):
    max1=31

elif(mm==4 or mm==6 or mm==9 or mm==11):
    max1=30

elif(yy%4==0 and yy%100!=0 or yy%400==0):
    max1=29
else:
    max1=28


if(mm<1 or mm>12 or dd<1 or dd>max1):
    print("Date is invalid.")



elif(dd==max1 and mm!=12):
    dd=1
    mm=mm+1
    print("The incremented date is: ",dd,mm,yy)

elif(dd==31 and mm==12):
    dd=1
    mm=1
    yy=yy+1
    print("The incremented date is: ",dd,mm,yy)

else:
    dd=dd+1
    print("The incremented date is: ",dd,mm,yy)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and fix your indentation. Please use 4 spaces for indentation, as this is the accepted community standard, defined in [PEP 8 -- The Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Your code as shown now is not runnable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Staying as close as possible to your original code, we can try:

```
def date_checker(date):
    dd,mm,yy=date.split('/')
    dd=int(dd)
    mm=int(mm)
    yy=int(yy)
    
    # Max days based on month value
    if(mm==1 or mm==3 or mm==5 or mm==7 or mm==8 or mm==10 or mm==12):
        max1=31
    elif(mm==4 or mm==6 or mm==9 or mm==11):
        max1=30
    elif(yy%4==0 and yy%100!=0 or yy%400==0):
        max1=29
    else:
        max1=28
    
    # Check month and day vals for validity
    if(mm<1 or mm>12 or dd<1 or dd>max1):
        print("Date is invalid.")
    else:
        print("Date is valid")
    # Iterate:
        if(dd==max1 and mm!=12):
            dd=1
            mm=mm+1
            print("The incremented date is: ",dd,"/",mm,"/",yy)
        elif(dd==31 and mm==12):
            dd=1
            mm=1
            yy=yy+1
            print("The incremented date is: ",dd,"/",mm,"/",yy)
        else:
            dd=dd+1
            print("The incremented date is: ",dd,"/",mm,"/",yy)
    
date = input("Enter the date: ")
date_checker(date)
```

A simpler approach might be to use the `datetime` package:

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

date = input("Enter the date: ")
try:
    date = datetime.strptime(date,"%d/%m/%Y")
    print("Date is valid.")
    print("The incremented date is: ",datetime.strftime(date + timedelta(days=1), format = "%d/%m/%Y"))
except ValueError:
    print("Date is invalid.")
```

Then the incremented date automatically wraps around months and years, and there's no need for so many if/else statements.

Comment: I have to do it without using any packages or inbuilt function. Is there any way for it?

Comment: The first approach doesn't require any packages, so that should be fine. If you don't want to define a `datechecker` function yourself then you could just have `date = input("Enter the date")` as your first line, and then copy the contents of that function above: `dd,mm,yy = date.split('/') ... else: dd = dd+1 print("The incremented date is: ",dd,"/",mm,"/",yy)`. I just defined it as a function so you can use the same chunk of code elsewhere - and the `datetime` solution was just a suggestion to simplify your code - but the first chunk should work fine! :)